# What happens if you get a check engine light and there's nothing wrong with the engine

Tags: engine, toyota, corolla

My father's 2014 Toyota Corolla recently had its check engine light pop on, but when he had my older brother check it out, it turned out nothing was wrong. He ignored it for about two weeks before he got concerned. He decided to bring it to the nearest auto repair shop run where a family friend works, and the same thing came up. There was nothing wrong with his car. At this point, it's been about a month, and the light is still on. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The light doesn't come on for "no reason". There has to be a code behind it, whether it's something which is innocuous or vehicle threatening, there's something there. Maybe the CEL is lit from a bad ground, who knows.

Comment: Agree with @Paulster2. If you took it to a mechanic and he did not put a scanner on it to check for codes I would take it to another mechanic.

Comment: Were they able to turn the lamp off?  If so, when did it come back on?

Comment: It's possible you have an intermittent error which throws a code, then self-corrects. Were there any codes showing at all?

Comment: Try AutoZone or other auto parts store for a free reading of error codes. When the engine symbol is on, there's at least one error code stored in memory waiting for a reader or scantool to decode it. Repair shops may be reluctant to provide info as this can affect their 'bottom line' if a customer goes elsewhere for info. You're always free to choose repair shops, dealers, independent mobile techs, auto parts stores providing free readings or friend with a reader/scantool. There are many readers and scantools to buy for primal use too.